# How to configure kafka brokers behind a TCP proxy

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, apache-kafka

I am trying to configure Kafka cluster behind nginx stream. 
My kafka is running in VM inside a VNet (intranet zone), I have another VM in which nginx  is runnig (internet Zone). I want to be able to connect kafka through proxy. I am not sure how to configure the advertised listeners.

suppose Nginx server is listening on port 8082, and my broker is listening in port 9092. Kindly help me .
Thanks